# ReferenceError: Flex is not defined

Tags: javascript, patches

I am receiving this error with an extension. I think this is related to the last patch 8788, anyone know how to solve it?

the error points me here

```
  var uploader = new Flex.Uploader('optionextended_link_'+selectId+'_file', OptionExtended.Config.uploaderUrl, this.uploaderConfig)
```

thanks

Comment: 8788 is removing certain swf files. When are you getting this error? At what section? what are you doing there?

Comment: http://prnt.sc/cz2emr I also tried reuploading swf files, but I think this is related to a .js file change. Maybe better revert patch?

Comment: Go to this folder skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/ in your server and see if patching removed flex.swf file.

If yes, that might be the reason for error. Your plugin is using those.

Just put it back will solve the issue. But its not at all recommended if you are using magento 1.9 and more. The swf file is removing to avoid vulnerabilities in magento, thats what patching do.

Comment: after putting trying refreshing cache.

Comment: I've just run into the same issue with custom options extension. Did you find a solution?

Comment: *bump* Have you found a soluton?

Comment: @Mediabeastnz have you found solution for this problem?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer have you found solution for that

Comment: The problem is, as previously stated, that magento replaced the flash uploader. Luckily for me, the extension provider had an update for me.